# If the father dies before his child is born, will it lose all claims?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I had a strange situation yesterday: One of my courtiers had a strong claim on an Irish county. I married him to one of my daughters, so I would sooner or later be able to get someone of my dynasty on their throne (or whatever the count equivalent for that is).

Then, the courtier died without giving me a grandchild. I thought all was lost, but a few months later my still widowed daughter had a child.

It was definitely his son, but it did not inherit his claim on the county. Shouldn't it have? I am pretty sure the same situation usually worked out when the father was still around on childbirth.

The situation in the county did not change in the meantime, so thats not the reason for the claim not being there.

Can somebody explain to me what happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Claims are passed on at the time of death. Your grandkid wasn't alive (in-game terms) at his father's death, ergo he doesn't get the claim.

Also, not all strong claims are inheritable (i.e. fabricated), though that likely isn't the case here.

Comment: That's what I feared. A bit unrealistic though, I thought you get a claim because you are related, not because you happen to be around at the time of death. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't get to inherit his claim, he would just be your vassal. If the father would be around when the son is born, he would still have his claims intact until his son will inherit from him etc.

So since the child was born and the father was dead, the child gets all his father's claims. I just hope that you married your daughter to the courtier matrilineally.

The new born is your kinsman now and it's in your bloodline which is what you wanted in the first place right?

Comment: Yes, married matrilineally. The problem is that the claim does not show in the sons character view. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @atticae your claim ? I think it's your kinsman claim, check the claimants under the Claims tab on the county's window.

Answer (score -1):

To expand slightly on Affine's answer ( I don't yet have the rep to comment on his answer):

Claims can pass through dead characters from grandparent to grandchild, even if the linking parent character is deceased before the birth of the child.

In my current game, I just married the eldest daughter of the king of Germany ( running agnatic-cognatic primogeniture). I had the sole male son and heir killed, but his wife was pregnant at the time. When the child was born, (even though the father was dead for months at this point) it became heir.